# How to deal with extremely big initial loss?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I build a model (glow) for image density estimation. It worked when using *CUB200* dataset for training, with images size `(224,224,3)` and 40 per batch. 
Loss function is calculate log probability using tensorflow_probability's distributions.
Initial loss is around `40000` and the rest of training went well. But if I use *celebA* dataset for training, the initial loss goes to like `1e+26` sometimes `Nan`.
Two datasets use same way to process, so I believe datasets should be fine.

The problem is I wonder what would cause such a high loss initially and how to deal with it because once it raised NaN error, training stops.

Comment: Did you normalize your images? I mean map each pixel from the range of (0,255) to (0,1) ?

Comment: @alift Yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

That means you have very low predicted probabilities for the true class at the beginning of training. This could mean that the initial values for the weights are too large, or that the input itself is not normalized, causing extreme outputs (very close to zero or one for a softmax output). You can fix this by:

- normalizing the inputs
- having smaller initial weights
- adding a small constant to the argument of the logarithm, so that the log will not be too large

Comment: What do you mean by adding a small constant to the argument of the logarithm? Can you please give me some examples? Thx!

Comment: @ABCMOONMAN999 for example, replace `log(x)` with `log(x+1e-6)`